# Changing hostname undone on reboot

Tags: networking

I need to change my RPi's hostname. I am familiar with the process: Change the hostname in /etc/hostname as well as in /etc/hosts. Then reboot. When I do that, however, on reboot, the hostname is back to the original value that was set before I changed it. The above two files are restored to their original form as well. What could be restoring these settings? Some DNS service perhaps? How can I troubleshoot this? Thank you!

The file settings follow:

/etc/hostname:

```
black-pearl1
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters


127.0.1.1       black-pearl1
```

Also, I checked /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and it starts with this:

```
#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
```

Comment: Without knowing how you "changed" or indeed, if, we can't help. The recommended method is through raspi-config.

Comment: Please, see the updated question. I'll try raspi-config, but I can't use that in the end because I need to be able to make these changes using a bash script.

Comment: That line is normal. It sends the hostname to the DHCP server. I have read the dhcpcd.conf manual, and frankly it is incomprehensible. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd is much easier to read. There are options for the server to set hostname.

Comment: All `raspi-config` does is change `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`.  Note that `dhclient` and `dhcpcd` are probably mutually exclusive; although Raspbian comes with both installed, I believe it only uses the latter by default (although you could check with `ps -C dhclient`, since it is persistent).

Comment: I think serverfault might be a better place to ask this question as it might be a Linux question rather than RPi specific one. Can someone with proper permissions migrate the question to ServerFault please? Is that a bad idea? I think the community is larger there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution. This is specific to my Raspberry Pi OS. I am running Hypriot on it, which is a Raspbian clone distro that has a built-in support for Docker containers. It also runs Occidentalis, which supervises certain processes and system configuration on boot, including the hostname. So, I had to go to /boot/occidentalis.txt and change the hostname there. Once I rebooted the Pi, the domain name was changed correspondingly. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: HypriotOS v1.1.1 from 14.11.2016 saves hostname in `/boot/device-init.yaml`

Comment: Latest HypriotOS versions use `cloud-init`, which has a `preserve_hostname` setting in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`. If you set that value to `true`, according to [this doc](https://help.switch.ch/engines/faq/ubuntu-why-cant-i-persistently-change-the-hostname-of-my-vm/), then you can manage the hostname and change it from the initial value. See also: [hostname can not be changed using normal CLI methods](https://github.com/hypriot/image-builder-rpi/issues/309#issuecomment-529192878)